# BATCH SET unable to use divide operator

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am unable to divide using the divide operator provided in the SET command.

> SET /A 216/18
>
> SET /A div=216/18
>
> ECHO %div%

Though this should work and it does in the command prompt window but when used through a batch script it gives a blank output.

like

> ECHO is on.

Whats wrong?

Comment: What means blank? For me, the script works.

Comment: Blank as in no output or if I direct the output to a text file then it creates an empty text file.
Also I agree that it should work as this is the basic syntax but it doesn't and it only works in cmd window.
I am using "Windows 7 Professional".

Comment: Have you added a "Pause"? I have written the code in notepad++ and it works as bat-script.

Comment: Works for me in a command prompt window.

Comment: File testbat.bat

`CD C:\DeleteLater`
`SET /A Div=216/3`
`ECHO /3 %Div% >> testbat.txt`

File testbat.txt
`/3 72`

Comment: Substitute `SET Div >> testbat.txt`  yields `Div=72` in testbat.txt

Comment: UPDATE:
It works in my friend's PC as well but as soon as I import the same script to my computer and run it, it doesn't work. We both share the same version of Windows and almost same config but it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if your `extenstions` are disabled. You can check `setlocal /?` and `cmd /?` for more information about `extensions`.

But the `set /?` specifies:

```
If Command Extensions are enabled SET changes as follows:  
...
Two new switches have been added to the SET command:  
  SET /A expression  
  SET /P variable=[promptString]
```

So without `extensions` the `/A` does not work.

You can add the `setlocal`-line to the top of your batchfile:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A 216/18
SET /A div=216/18
ECHO %div%
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I added the lines and the dos bat file still can't do division.

> But, I admit that reading the help on the topic made no sense.

Here is the bat code, and what is wrong?:

:DOS can't do division
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

SET hours2record=13
SET minutes2record=05
SET tracklength=46800

set /a seconds = %hours2record% * 3600 + %minutes2record% * 60
echo so far so good.  Seconds are %seconds%
pause

::SET /A trackdiv=%seconds%/46800  does not work
::SET /A trackdiv=468000/46800    works
::SET /A trackdiv=seconds/46800   does not work either
SET /A %seconds%/%tracklength%
SET /A trackdiv=%seconds%/%tracklength%      &   does not work

echo trackdiv variable is calculated as %trackdiv%   .  This is wrong!  47100/46800 does not equal 1!  Stupid dos!
pause

setlocal /?
pause
cmd /?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168065)